# передача даты в БД

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, access, sharepoint

Необходимо передать значения даты в список Share Point (по сути БД). Передаю с помощью ajax запросов.

```
$.ajax({
       url: endPoint,
       type: "POST",
       headers: requestHeaders,
       data: JSON.stringify(data_obj),
       success:function(){
...
```

JSON.stringify превращает дату из объекта data_obj в строку, в итоге БД не пускает в поле с форматом даты значение строки. Как передать через ajax запросы значение даты?

Comment: А зачем вы делаете JSON.stringify() ?

Comment: в примерах, на которых я обучался, использвался способ {data: JSON.stringify(data_obj)}. Если посоветуете другие способы передачи /что почитать на эту тему - буду благодарен

Comment: Для боди пост запроса нет необходимости приводить объект к json строке, вы можете прикладывать ваш объект данных без приведения к строке. Тут подробнее про запросы и их параметры https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods, соответственно для боди запроса действуют те же ограничения, что и для JSON.

Comment: К сожалению не сработало - 400 ошибка {Недопустимый JSON. Неизвестный токен в содержимом JSON.}. Возможно это стоило указать с самого начала, для обмена данными я использую технологию REST API

Comment: Без полного примера вашего кода, пример отправляемого JSON’а хотя бы тяжело ответить. Обновите ваш вопрос и добавьте туда пример и лог ошибки.